# Taking archive backup from Amazon Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

How can I restore my archive from amazon glacier?

I installed mt-aws-glacier package on ubuntu machine.Also created configure file(glacier.cfg) into root path and add the access and Secret keys then executed the below command.

**command :**

```
mtglacier --config ../glacier.cfg --vault xxx  retrieve-inventory
```

**output**

PID 6833 Retrieved Inventory, job id pI-xxxxx8xyxxmxtcccxxxxxrFHyLgm

```
mtglacier --config ../glacier.cfg --vault xxxx download-inventory --new-journal journal.new
```

**output**

ERROR (child 6842): Unexpected reply from remote server
EXIT on SIGCHLD (exit_code 1)

please help on this issue.

Comment: Have you waited for 4+ hours (as suggested in the mt-aws-glacier docs) for the inventory retrieval to complete?

Comment: If execute the command.Immediately getting error.

Comment: But i can able to upload the files from  cloudbeerylab GUI tool.